# why does loading my homepage leads to my index page?

Tags: web-development, website-design

please when ever i load my new site quancer[dot ]com. It leads to  my index page. I just installed the script using softaculous autoinstaller. Please kindly help me with this.

Comment: which script did you install? Did you have a homepage before? A little more info would be nice.

Comment: homepage != index page?

Comment: @w3d: there's no index file in the root folder, only 3 other folders...

Comment: As the other answers suggest, there could be a .htaccess file in the root that is rewriting the URL to a file in one of the sub folders.

Answer (score 1):

Point the domain to qtoa/ folder, not the root of the host, or if that's not possible:

- Create an index file in the root that automatically redirects to the qtoa/ folder
- Create a .htacces file that rewrites the url hiding the qtoa/ folder from the url
- move the contents of the qtoa/ folder to the root

Answer (score 1):

Usually in any web server first
index.php
index.html
default.php
These pages will load if these files are not available then only it will show all filders and files in your root directory ( based on web user permissions )

Use .htaccess file to change the welcome or homepage file
or use redirection to the sub directory ( if u install any script like cms usually it will extract in /script-name-version , you need to extract carefully while choosing directory name )